# Issue getting the azure translator to work with Android

Tags: java, android, language-translation, microsoft-translator

My android app used the old microsoft Translator very well but I am having
problems getting the app to work with the new Cognitive Services.

First I got a new azure translation account that has the following values
(these are not the real values)

Name: MYTranslateAcct

Resource group: translate

subscription ID: 981h5ce7-7ac7-4f6f-b4a5-ff04dc9e4266

key1 d122230418a8479ab5c06f2f1fca664c

key2 39c1f187o9814f4e983jba9eedd2e2c7

My first step is to try to get a token.  Microsoft has docs on doing
this in JAVA but not in an Android environment.  I dug around and have
put together some code but it is not working.  One problem is that the
docs use terms that I don't have in my account such as "app-id" and
"key".  I don't have those things - I just have the list of values
above.

Here is my code . . .

> ```
> class translateMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
> {
>     String retString;
>     String inString = null;
>
>     translateMessage(String inString) { this.inString = inString; }
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>
>
>             String key = "881b5ce7-9ac7-4f6f-b4a5-ff04dc9e3199";
>             String authenticationUrl = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";
>             HttpsURLConnection authConn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(authenticationUrl).openConnection();
>             authConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
>             authConn.setDoOutput(true);
>             authConn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
>             IOUtils.write("", authConn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");       //following line of code gets the exception . . .
>             String token = IOUtils.toString(authConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");  //this blows
>        }
>         catch (Exception e)
>         {
>             String myString = e.getMessage();
>             String aString = "look at e";
>
>         }
>         return retString;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(String result)
>     {
>         String debugStr = result;
>         translation.setText(result);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Following is the exception . . .
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken

What am I doing wrong?
Is anyone aware of any working Android java code using the new services?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on Azure support and someone called me within an hour.  I was passing the wrong key.  When you get a translate cognitive account you get Key1 and Key2.  Either of them will work.  So the code is a useful example of working code that will get a token.